# how to set checkbox color for chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, checkbox

In my application I am showing a graph with legends. Legends have colored checkboxes. Below is code for a checkbox that works fine in `IE` but the color does not appear in `Chrome` and `Firefox`

`<input type="checkbox" style="background-color:#d65aef;">`

Please tell me what should I do so that it works in `IE`,`Chrome` and `Firefox`. I have to use the hex color as used in the given code.

Comment: It's been a while, but maybe consider marking Pinal's response as answer using the checkmark below the voting buttons :)

Answer (score 28):

Form controls like `checkbox`, `radio`, `select` and etc using a platform-native styling based on the operating system's theme. You can reset it by using [`-moz-appearance` and `-webkit-appearance` properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance). But this properties will also reset sizes of control and may be something else, so you will need to add width/height manually:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
     background: red;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}
```

Also for checkbox you need to provide a checked state render:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked {
     background-image: url(/*custom checked icon url*/);
}
```

Comment: this should be marked as the correct answer. Thanks a lot @Pinal

Comment: This didn't work for me. Even though, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Close `input` into `span` (or `div`) and set `span` color.

```
<span style="background-color:#d65aef;"><input type="checkbox" class="base" name="w3wp" style="background-color:#d65aef;" value="w3wp" checked="" onclick="legendChanged();" alt="fd" title="w3wp"></span>
```

Comment: by this color shows, but check box goes some above from then color, check box should be just in middle , how can I set it in middle