# Checkbox tick colour issue IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am changing tick color using attached code it working fine in chrome but not working in IE. Please help

IE Code updated due to apperance not allowing

```js
$('input+div').on('click', function(){    
    debugger;
    
        if ($(this).prev().prop('checked')==false){ 
           $(this).prev().attr('checked', true);  
        }
    else{
       $(this).prev().attr('checked', false);  
        }
        $(this).toggleClass("checkbox-checked-replica");      
      });
```

```css
.checkbox-checked-replica{
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border: solid 1px;
    vertical-align: middle;
 display: inline-block;
 background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxukt.png) no-repeat center;
 }
 .checkbox-unchecked-replica{
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border: solid 1px;
    vertical-align: middle; 
 display: inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" style=" border: solid 1px #a1a6ac;height:20px;width:20px">
<div class="checkbox-unchecked-replica"></div>
```

js -->

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  var imageURL = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxukt.png';
  var c = this.checked ? ($(this).css('-webkit-appearance', 'none'),
    $(this).css('-moz-appearance', 'none'), $(this).css(' appearance', 'none'), $(this).css('background-position', 'center'), $(this).css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat'), $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + imageURL + ')')) : $(this).css('-webkit-appearance', 'checkbox');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" style=" border: solid 1px #a1a6ac;height:20px;width:20px">
<div class="checkbox-unchecked-replica"></div>
```

Comment: IE doesn't let you change the appearance of checkbox controls in the manner you're attempting. As a workaround you'd need to create another element, such as a `div`, which you can use to 'fake' the UI of the checkbox. Also note that you should really use `addClass()` or `removeClass()` to set the styling rules.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for your input but any way to hide tick.Like i did to hide down arrow in dropdown list select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}

Comment: Man that is a bad use of a ternary operator.

Comment: @epascarello I will use if else

Comment: Why don't you just have css to do the styles? `input[type="checkbox"] {} input[type="checkbox"]:checked { }`

Comment: @epascarello nice. I will do in your way

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301673/how-to-set-checkbox-color-for-chrome

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan update as you  suggested but still it is firing multiple click event