# Checkbox disabled not changing color in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a checkbox that is disabled but i want the background to be dark grey but i cant seem to get it to work, the css doesnt change the color:
Here is .js code:

```
export const CheckBoxRowItem = (props) => {
var readOnly = props.onChange == null;
var disabled = props.disabled || false;

return (
    <div className="row row-no-padding">
        <label className="control-label col-md-3">{props.title}</label>
        <div className="controls col-md-9">
            <input type="checkbox" className="checkboxSelect large-check-box" placeholder={props.title}
                checked={props.value || false} readOnly={readOnly} disabled={disabled}
            />
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

}

and the css:

```
input[type=checkbox][disabled]{
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to set checkbox color for chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301673/how-to-set-checkbox-color-for-chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The css is changing the color, but the platform-native styling based on the operating system's theme overlays that, so it is hidden.

You can reset it by using [`-moz-appearance` and `-webkit-appearance` properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance).
However, these properties will sometimes also reset sizes on some devices, so you will need to add width/height manually:

```
input[type=checkbox][disabled]{
    background: red;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
}
```

This will also remove the tick, so you could add `background-image: url(...);` to add one back in